# DISTINCT not eliminating the duplicate records- Why?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, db2

DISTINCT is not working as usual on DB2 database query

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT PF1
FROM
    (
        SELECT
                DISTINCT PF1
            FROM
                RELATIONS
        UNION
        SELECT
                DISTINCT PF2
            FROM
                RELATIONS
    )
WHERE
    PF1 NOT IN (
        SELECT
                DISTINCT NAME
            FROM
                REFERENCES
            WHERE
                TYPE = 'F'
    );
```

This query is giving duplicate results as

```
C1:PROV
C1:PROV
WK:HEADER
WK:HEADER
WK:HEADER
etc
```

What thing/setting is responsible for this abnormal behavior??

**FYI**: Same query gives correct result on another machine's database.

**Edited**
Here are the table's structure

```
CREATE TABLE RELATIONS (
    PF1 VARCHAR(54) NOT NULL,
    PF1TXT VARCHAR(50),
    PF2 VARCHAR(54) NOT NULL,
    SEQ DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PF2TXT VARCHAR(50),
  UNIQUE (PF1, SEQ, PF2)
);

CREATE TABLE REFERENCES (
    NAME1 VARCHAR(54) NOT NULL,
    NAMETXT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(54) NOT NULL,
    TYPE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (NAME1, NAMETXT, NAME, TYPE) 
);
```

Comment: can you share the table atributes ?

Comment: what kind of output that you want? list of distinct values?

Comment: Yes @stormrage, I just want the unique result without duplication.

Comment: your query is alright. i tried on mysql and it gives correct result. but i have to rename your REFERENCES table into REFERENCE because it's somehow a keyword and returns error if i don't change it. I'm not so sure, but try renaming it.

Comment: No @stormrage, no need to rename the table name, I already posted the changed tables/fields name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION` should already be eliminating duplicates. You could re-structure your query a little bit, and it should work. I only made the `REFS` CTE, in case your actual code was more complicated than that, as to reduce duplication:

```
WITH REFS (NAME) AS (
    SELECT NAME
    FROM REFERENCES
    WHERE TYPE = 'F'
)

SELECT PF1
FROM RELATIONS
WHERE PF1 NOT IN (
    SELECT NAME FROM REFS
)

    UNION 

SELECT PF2
FROM RELATIONS
WHERE PF2 NOT IN (
    SELECT NAME FROM REFS
)
```

I tested this on my DB2 for LUW 9.7, and it worked correctly for me.

Comment: Thx @bhamby, this query is working fine with a little change.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but you could give an alias to your derived table. In my test it worked.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PF1 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PF1 FROM RELATIONS
        UNION SELECT DISTINCT PF2 FROM RELATIONS
    )  as rel -- the name to derived table
WHERE PF1 NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM REFERENCES
        WHERE TYPE = 'F');
```

Comment: Well, @Bill what you said in your answer was just what I answered here, 2 hours before.

Comment: Yes @TioDavid its a same copy, and not eliminating the duplicates.

Comment: @Kishore I had a similar trouble, but in the end was the version of DB2. I made my queries on version 10.0 and production was 9.7. But, I see you choose an answer and it's very good. Good luck :)